# Cross Search generate char Matrix

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a word search puzzle matrix, this is the code I have,

```
static void PlaceWords(List<string> words)
    {
        Random rn = new Random();
        foreach (string p in words)
        {
            String s = p.Trim();
            bool placed = false;
            while (placed == false)
            {
                int nRow = rn.Next(0,10);
                int nCol = rn.Next(0,10);
                
                int nDirX = 0;
                int nDirY = 0;
                while (nDirX == 0 && nDirY == 0)
                {
                    nDirX = rn.Next(3) - 1;
                    nDirY = rn.Next(3) - 1;
                }

                placed = PlaceWord(s.ToUpper(), nRow, nCol, nDirX, nDirY);
            }
        }
    }

    static bool PlaceWord(string s, int nRow, int nCol, int nDirX, int nDirY)
    {
        bool placed = false;
        int LetterNb = s.Length;

        int I = nRow;
        int J = nCol;
        if (MatriceIndice[nRow, nCol] == 0)
        {
            placed = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length-1; i++)
            {
                I += nDirX;
                J += nDirY;
                if (I < 10 && I>0 && J < 10 && J>0)
                {
                    if (MatriceIndice[I, J] == 0)
                        placed = placed && true;
                    else
                        placed = placed && false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(placed==true)
        {
            int placeI = nRow;
            int placeJ = nCol;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                placeI += nDirX;
                placeJ += nDirY;
                MatriceIndice[placeI,placeJ] = 1;
                MatriceChars[placeJ, placeJ] = s[i];
            }
        }
        return placed;
    }
```

However it seems like it is an infinite loop. I am trying to add the code in a 10*10 char matrix linked to a 10*10 int matrix initially filled with 0 where I change the cases to 1 if the word is added to the matrix. How should I fix the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors. First,

```
MatriceChars[placeJ, placeJ] = s[i];
```

should be

```
MatriceChars[placeI, placeJ] = s[i];
```

Second,

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - 1; i++)
```

(two occurrences) should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
```

(You do want all the letters in the words, right?)

Third, when testing indices, you should use `I >= 0`, not `I > 0`, as the matrix indices start at 0.

However, the main logic of the code seems to work, but if you try to place too many words, you will indeed enter an infinite loop, since it just keeps trying and failing to place words that can never fit.